# NODE+PASSPORT+LINKEDIN 500 InternalOAuthError failed to obtain request token

Tags: node.js, api, linkedin-api, passport.js

I'm working with passport-linkedin and I'm getting this error:
500 InternalOAuthError: failed to obtain request token

I'm using:
node v0.12.3
express 3.20.3
passport-linkedin@0.1.3 
passport-oauth@0.1.15 (oauth@0.9.13, passport@0.1.18)

My code

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var passport = require('passport');
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
      done(null, user);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
      done(null, obj);
    });

var app = express();
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());

// begin linkedin passport -->
var LinkedInStrategy  = require('passport-linkedin').Strategy;
var LINKEDIN_API_KEY = "--key--"
var LINKEDIN_SECRET_KEY = "--secret--";

passport.use(new LinkedInStrategy({
    consumerKey: LINKEDIN_API_KEY,
    consumerSecret: LINKEDIN_SECRET_KEY,
    callbackURL: "http://www.mywebsite.com:3000/auth/linkedin/callback"
  },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    process.nextTick(function () {
        console.log("--------------LINKEDIN USER DATA--------------");     
        console.log("profile.id: "+profile.id);     
        console.log(profile);
        console.log("----------------------------------------"); 
        return done(null, profile);
    });
  }
));

app.get('/auth/linkedin',
  passport.authenticate('linkedin', { scope : ['r_basicprofile',     'r_emailaddress'] } ),
   function(req, res){
    // The request will be redirected to LinkedIn for authentication, so this
    // function will not be called.
  });

app.get('/auth/linkedin/callback', 
    passport.authenticate('linkedin', { 
        successRedirect : '/home',
        failureRedirect: '/login'
    })
);
// <-- end linkedin passport

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Thanks in advance!